# Renaming Spring Data jpa Id column

Tags: hibernate, attributes, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

From my entity I'm trying to rename the id column field defined in AbstractPersistable by Spring Data Jpa using AttributeOverride annotation.

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="user_id"))
public class User extends AbstractPersistable<Long>  {
...
```

this is failing with the exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(user) and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

the only time the above definition is passing and the DDL is generated is when I define the column name as ID like

```
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="ID"))
```

Seems like a bug to me. I really don't get what the problem is.

Comment: Is `AbstractPersistable<T>` annotated with `@MappedSuperclass` ?

Comment: Yes, it is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/AbstractPersistable.java

Comment: What if you add `@Table(name="\"user\"")` to the entity ?

Comment: thanks a lot for the tip but it is still failing with the same error message :/ I really can't explain why

Comment: I just had to deal with this same problem. Can you show the rest of your class? Are you declaring the id field? If you are, you need to take it out of your entity object. Meaning, keep your @AttributeOverride annotation where it is, but if you are declaring the id field in the body, remove that.