# Cannot override default id column spring data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, spring-data-jpa

I recently refactored our database schema to have the id columns in each of our tables to be in the format "tableName" + ID, IE "SettingsID" instead of just "id" across all tables. Now my spring-data backend is breaking when I try to fetch anything from one of those tables. It complains that there is an "invalid column name 'id'". I assume what I need to do is map my new name of the ID column to what spring data wants to be the id column, but I havent been successful so far.

I think the only configuration needed would happen within my entity object. Here is my Settings.java entity object class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Settings.TABLE_NAME)
public class Settings extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "SETTINGS";

@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name="settingsID"))
private long settingsID;

@Column(name = "CUSTOMERID")
private String customerID;

@Column(name = "MERCHANTID")
private String merchantID;
...
....
}
```

And just in case it matters, (Which I don't think it does) here is the function I am calling when this error is thrown:

```
@Repository
public interface SettingsDAO extends CrudRepository<Settings, Long> {


/**
 * Finds the entry in the Settings table for a given customerID
 * @param customerID   The customerID to search for
 * @return             The settings object for the given customer ID
 */
Settings findOneByCustomerID(String customerID);

}
```

The error I get is (beside from the generic hibernate error saying it cant extract the resultset) is

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'id'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316502/renaming-spring-data-jpa-id-column) post, I realized that I wasn't supposed to add the @AttributeOverride annotation on the field, but the class itself. That way, spring data will not try to double map the id field. My new entity object looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Settings.TABLE_NAME)
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="SETTINGSID"))
public class Settings extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "SETTINGS";


@Column(name = "CUSTOMERID")
private String customerID;

@Column(name = "MERCHANTID")
private String merchantID;
...
```

Notice there is no field for id now.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this name/value pair to the application.properties worked for me without having to use the AttributeOverride annotation

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```